# Combobox based on another combobox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to do the following. I am selecting an item from a combobox then I want the values of the next combobox to be the result of a query based on the first selection. This is what I have so far.... HTML

```
    <fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="custom-select" name="serviciuSelect" id="serviciuSelect" onchange="arataAngajat()">
      <option selected="">Selecteaza serviciul dorit</option>
      <?php foreach ($servicii as $item): ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo $item['denumire']; ?>"><?php echo $item['denumire']; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
 </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="custom-select" name="angajatSelect" id="angajatSelect" style="visibility: hidden">
      <option selected="">Selecteaza angajatul dorit</option>
      <!-- <?php foreach ($angajati as $item): ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo $item['nume']; ?>"><?php echo $item['nume']; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach;?> -->
    </select>
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

JavaScript

```
    <script>
    function arataAngajat() {
        document.getElementById("angajatSelect").style.visibility = "visible";
        var e = document.getElementById("serviciuSelect").value;
        document.cookie = "selectSer = " + e;  
   }
   </script>
```

PHP

```
    <?php 
function getSelectServiciu(){
    $selectServiciu= $_COOKIE['selectSer'];
    $query = "SELECT COD_A FROM angajat WHERE COD_A IN (
    SELECT COD_A FROM angajat_serviciu WHERE COD_S='".
    $selectServiciu."')";
    $result = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
    return $result;
}
    ?>
```

I got stuck when I had to call the PHP function getSelectServiciu(). Also, If there's a better way of doing this, please let me know.

Thanks,
Tibi

Comment: The JavaScript and cookie will be on the client side, the PHP executes on the server.  You need to 'post' or 'get' the cookie info to the server then run your PHP when you receive and process this.

Comment: did you check value of  **$_COOKIE['selectSer']**

Comment: i have all the code on the same page. should i create a separate php file to handle this query? and how to call this function when changing the item in combobox?

Answer (score 0):

this script is get data from server under a service display as a combobox options

services.php

```
<?php

//i'm using array u can use mysql array
$services=array();
$services[]=array('name'=>'Flowers');
$services[]=array('name'=>'Fruits');

//data under services
$data=array();
$data['Flowers']=array('Rose','Belly');
$data['Fruits']=array('Banana','Mango');

//check the the client is requested for data under a service
if(isset($_GET['get_data'])){
$current_service=$_GET['get_data'];
$data_array=$data[$current_service];
echo  '<option selected="">Select</option>';
foreach($data_array as $op){
echo  '<option value="'.$op.'">'.$op.'</option>';
}
}else{
?>
 <fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="custom-select" name="Services" id="Services" onchange="Getnext_option(this.value)">
      <option selected="">Select</option>
      <?php foreach ($services as $item): ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo $item['name']; ?>"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></option> <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
 </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="custom-select" name="Loaded_data" id="Loaded_data" style="display: none"> </select>
 </div>
</fieldset>

<script>function Getnext_option(id){
var load_to=document.getElementById('Loaded_data');
load_to.style.display="none";
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      load_to.innerHTML=
      this.responseText;
        load_to.style.display="block";
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET","services.php?get_data="+id, true);//get data from server
  xhttp.send();
}</script>

<?php } ?>
```